# SQL SERVER error 15208: CREATE ASSEMBLY WITH PERMISSION_SET = EXTERNAL_ACCESS on SQL SERVER 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, sqlclr

I created  a library in VS2008 who converts this(http://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml) xml on IEnumerable. When I added the library in Assemblies of db. After that I created a function with Input the currencies link and output: Currency and rate. The code for add the dll:

```
CREATE ASSEMBLY Currencies
FROM 'C:\Currencies.dll'
WITH PERMISSION_SET = EXTERNAL_ACCESS
```

This work fine in SQL SERVER 2008, but I must put some library on SQL SERVER 2005 but in this case I can't create a assembly with EXTERNAL_ACCESS. For create a assembly with external_access i must create ASTIMETRIC KEY and LOGIN, that I read on this site: [http://64.4.10.89/ru-ru/library/ms345106(v=sql.90).aspx](http://64.4.10.89/ru-ru/library/ms345106%28v=sql.90%29.aspx). I use this code:

```
USE master 
GO  

CREATE ASYMMETRIC KEY CurrenciesKey FROM EXECUTABLE FILE = 'C:\Currencies.dll'   
CREATE LOGIN CurrenciestLogin FROM ASYMMETRIC KEY CurrenciesKey   
GRANT EXTERNAL ACCESS ASSEMBLY TO CurrenciesLogin 
GO
```

but after that I have the error codes: 
Msg: 15208...
Msg: 15151...
Msg: 4621...

How I can solve SQL SERVER Error 15208?

Can anybody help me?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this problem without CREATE ASYMMETRIC...! I build my Class Library Currencies but I changed Target Framework: from .net framwork 3.5 into .net framework  2.0 and change some in cod to run with framework 2.0. After I create assembly with new dll and it's work fine!